# Access child component state in other ways than ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to use something like `this.refs.child.state` in my application to access state of a child component, hence need an alternative way to do so. Main reason for this is to pass child contents to redux state when a certain button is clicked inside such childs parent component, hence function in parent component needs to pass childs content as one of the parameters.

Comment: why can't you use `refs`?

Comment: @dandavis I'm not entirely sure to be honest, I specify `ref="someRef"` on my child component, but it is not displayed when I look it up with inspector. The way I use them is I have my `<ParentComponent>{this.props.children}</ ParentCimponent>` where children are other components.

Comment: @dandavis chlidren components being ones I put ref on that gets ignored

Comment: the easy way is to define them close together and use closure so that lifecycle code can share psudeo-globals. you can use real globals to, or dispatch() from a method on the child or in JSX itself. you can also subscribe to events on the parent and trigger them on the child, since events bubble up. you can also use a function-based `ref=` to push the interesting elm on the child into somewhere reachable.

Comment: @dandavis could you please provide expanded answer with code examples, as I am not entirely understanding your ideas here (new to react)

Comment: i've never actually written any react code (gotta grudge against fb for trash talking html5), but i've looked into it a lot. checkout http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/ for ideas and example of most of my suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried creating a public accessor method in the child component ,eg :
getChildState = () => {return this.state}). Then, simply this.refs.someRef.getState()

Comment: When you say **content**, do you mean the text displayed by the button? Is that content not passed as a prop from the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the structure of your components (hard to tell when you don't post code), you could fix this just by chaining callbacks via props.  I.e.

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
    onChange: function(childValue){
        this.setState({childValue: childValue});
    },
    render: function(){
        return <Child onChange={this.onChange} />
    }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    handleChange: function(event){
        this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
    },
    render: function(){
        return <input onChange={this.handleChange}/>
    }
});
```

Add in as many middle-layers as needed of the form;

```
var MiddleChildA = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <MiddleChildB onChange={this.props.onChange} />
    }
});
```